# HTML, js, ajax form action="", after first send XMLHttpRequest stop working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using a XMLHttpRequest to get data from another server. The JS is executed from the keyup-event from a input-field in my html-document.
After i've sent the formular data one time to the same html-document the XMLHttpRequest stops working.
I used this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_callback

HTML

```
<label for="lieferant">Lieferant:</label>
<input name="lieferant" id="eintragen_lieferant" value="' . $lieferant . '" type="text" maxlength="50" onkeyup="eintragen_get_lieferanten(this.value)">
<div id="eintragen_lieferanten"></div>
```

js

```
function loadxhtml(url, cfunc)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function eintragen_get_lieferanten(value)
{
  loadxhtml("functions/eintragen_get_lieferanten.php?suchstring=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "&lol=" + timestamp, function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("eintragen_lieferanten").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }         
         );
```

}

php

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM lieferant WHERE name LIKE '%" . $suchstring . "%'";

$result = $con->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<br>" . $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Can someone tell my, why the xhtmlrequest stops working after i've sent the data to the same php/html file (aciton="")?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: [Exploits of a mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) -> [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: This is a simplified example. I know what sql injection is and how to avoid it.

Comment: Then why you're not using prepared statements? Nevertheless, check the network tab of the developer tools and use the debugger to step through the code to see what is happening and where it "breaks"